# Not able to fetch json (api) data through angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm not able to fetch data through angularjs, it shows  blank screen on chrome while running it, don't know the issue since I'm a beginner.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{Word}}{{names}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4ouukv7c/31/)

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:Finally, I got the solution, after trying for couple of hours,needed to get CORS extension from chrome:[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4ouukv7c/31/)

Comment: Does the page you request return a JSON response?

Comment: yes,here is the link which im targetting http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php?callback=RandomWordComplete&_=1449231926094

Comment: **Side Note** don't use too older version..do upgrade it..

Comment: the jsfiddle doesnt work because you're not including angularjs in the html. You need to add it in a script tag

Comment: i added it i just pasted a part of the code

Comment: I can't see why this question was down voted? he provided a fiddle which showed the problem?

Answer (score 1):

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Cross Origin Requests don't seem to be allowed for your resource API

Updating your request you can add an error response in to catch such problems

```
$http.get("http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php")
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response.data;
    console.log(response);
  },
       function(error){
    console.log('error',error);    
  });
```

edit:
No idea who marked this down but I changed the api call to one which allows cors and made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leewinter/w3ugcakg/) to show it working.

dom

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in names.data">
        {{x.title}}
      </li>
    </ul>
            <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.names = response;
  }, function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

If your angular app is hosted separately to your API then you will have a little [work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to allow access.

Comment: Do me a favor and leave a comment for down votes. If I didn't explain something very well it would be nice to know.

Comment: Agree with you about the down vote. Reckon your answer is spot on so I'm going to give you an up vote.

Comment: thanks a lot this works great definitely " +1" from my side !!! but any idea how to fetch it from http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php

Comment: @neelabhsingh the fiddle may not be working because its not hosted on the same domain but if your angular app was hosted @ randomword.setgetgo.com/index.html you should have more luck

Comment: okk ! actually I wanted to have a single meaningflu  word at a time,yes there is some issue that i'm not able to do it with this one...

Comment: @neelabhsingh whats the issue?